# javascript ajax Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript

when i use ajax to bring information at this line it tells me Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list at this line

```
$.each('data.color',function(key,value){
      $('select[name="color"]').append('<option value=" 'value' ">" 'value' "</option>');
});
```

please help

here is my code javascript ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click','#addcart',function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    // console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/product/view/modal/'+id,
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(data){
        // console.log(data);
        $('#pname').text(data.product.name_en);
        $('#price').text(data.product.selling_price);
        $('#pcode').text(data.product.code);
        $('#pcategory').text(data.product.category.name_en);
        $('#pbrand').text(data.product.brand.brand_name_en);
        $('#pimage').attr('src','images/'+data.product.thumbnail);
        $.each('data.color',function(key,value){
          $('select[name="color"]').append('<option value=" 'value' ">" 'value' "</option>');
        });
      }
    })        
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `'<option value=" 'value' ">" 'value' "</option>'` needs some `+` operators to concatenate the parts: `'<option value=" '+value+' ">" '+value+' "</option>'`. You most likely want `'<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'` though

Comment: You can tell by the colors that something is wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the argument either way:

```js
append(`<option value="${value}">"${value}"</option>`)
```

or

```js
append('<option value="' + value + '">"' + value +'"</option>')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
.append('<option value=" 'value' ">" 'value' "</option>');
                          ^
                          |
                        ERROR
```

Javascript detects that you are trying to start a new statement but have not finished the previous statement. Therefore it checks what was the last statement and notices that you have not closed the `.append()` function. So it is telling you that the `)` is missing.

Of course, you do not intend to start a new statement but rather continue with an expression. What you want is this:

```
.append('<option value=" ' + value + ' ">" ' + value + ' "</option>');

        \_________________________ ______________________________/
                                  V
                Now this whole part is an expression
```